# Linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181

Tags: rust

I'm trying to setup the [muiltiparty threshold ECDSA](https://github.com/KZen-networks/multi-party-ecdsa) with the the command "cargo build --release --examples“ (following the readme.md's instruction). And the error occurs.

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181

  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_
64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\
\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\re
lease\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manage
r.240f29m0-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcod
e\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\re
lease\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.
240f29m0-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.sm_manager.240f29m0-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/OUT:F:\\rustco
de\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.exe" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\examples\\sm_manager.8p2ouoz6ndal2d.rcgu.o" "/OPT:REF,ICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64
-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\r
ustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libstd.natvis" "/LIBPATH:F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps" "/LIBPATH:F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-mas
ter\\target\\release\\build\\secp256k1-1be602a1be1c6b00\\out" "/LIBPATH:F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\build\\rust-crypto-c62eada8941b8567\\out" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rust
lib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsecp256k1-5aff06d8c00a6316.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libhmac_drbg-f091fbbb7d279562.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecds
a-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcrunchy-d13d013e6995cc21.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsubtle-890c2a171eb84060.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libreqwest-a6ff5e3f532c1479.rlib" "F:
\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libwinreg-937d82d573dcf9ed.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libuuid-ce0357aa89aba093.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libserde_url
encoded-beedab6f00219257.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libdtoa-7ac9db45ef55aca5.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmime_guess-f5c354e6b50e4077.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-maste
r\\target\\release\\deps\\libunicase-9cac21d1a5c1dec6.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmime-8373f626b2ee65cf.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libflate2-52a15a8d97992de9.rlib" "F:\\rustcode
\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libminiz_oxide-69eccb52a1565152.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libadler32-6369951ed0f93397.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcrc32fast-6
c597eb860b0c5a0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libhyper-5fe44c52da6e4189.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libwant-3ceb661b2b40894b.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\rel
ease\\deps\\libtry_lock-0107bb6b9f3163a1.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio-413da5b08cfa6ee4.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_timer-2d4f6360e8da7bb4.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi
-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_threadpool-41cdd56635169a60.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcrossbeam_queue-7957d04bf7221979.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcross
beam_deque-e6c8d232a3e0724d.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcrossbeam_epoch-ef6b41d73ce4f361.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmemoffset-ca0539aa13d671d0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-part
y-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_tcp-44d76419c422159f.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_reactor-1b693f10e1287169.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_sync-c683c01d
fe7222c2.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libparking_lot-b1c9a8e18489f267.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libparking_lot_core-36de122f113aedb0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\
target\\release\\deps\\libsmallvec-7f7456013fe8fd77.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmaybe_uninit-6441a5977ae0a1cf.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\liblock_api-0cf97a0bc5225333.rlib" "F:\\
rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libscopeguard-7a3eb969329f6a44.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_current_thread-0a6db2451725f4ef.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\
deps\\libtokio_executor-5df001a1b86b51f0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcrossbeam_utils-c5dc190f95fd578f.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmio-1f8c1eec22686f6c.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\mul
ti-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmiow-8968b8fbfb81f0e6.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libws2_32-7299a572329aadf7.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libkernel32-7d5e7071ca743f4
7.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libwinapi-339901690fbef76a.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libnet2-c5d9645590e862e1.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\l
ibhttp_body-c23449f632528f78.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_buf-8e9d5fcdb900a3fc.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libh2-d5324feb129ed8e3.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-mast
er\\target\\release\\deps\\libstring-aeaa0fcdbb0febc2.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libslab-a52ec2eb4c1c50fe.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtokio_io-51dd14d9ed9456e1.rlib" "F:\\rustco
de\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libfutures_cpupool-72f1dc8605f9d8d0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libhttp-84f77248592eac88.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libfnv-203c
2058730c2b10.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libfutures-5574d475975657e4.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libencoding_rs-a9068aae1b8da1ef.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\targe
t\\release\\deps\\libcookie_store-c1f9909d9bfc03e2.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libpublicsuffix-a13accc6b66c0897.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\liburl-1ac1cca4398d2feb.rlib" "F:\\rustco
de\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libpercent_encoding-2931a4346acb2f17.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libidna-80e02a989d5c51a4.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libregex-7
80a8640cf18aee1.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libregex_syntax-8a0767d1c1252efa.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\liblazy_static-f87bece2c4bf1a5e.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-maste
r\\target\\release\\deps\\liberror_chain-e03f672a0bb633ce.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtry_from-408ccf0a7145d285.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libfailure-e61f3c5145cbd1fe.rlib" "F:\
\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libbacktrace-46983df57a9d81a6.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librustc_demangle-30ec7aaae01831d0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\
libcookie-3241869e8cb2d610.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libbytes-8af7810dfd10a5fb.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libeither-a998067f777735bc.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master
\\target\\release\\deps\\libiovec-5142677e4c1ec571.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcurv-4be9c439b3d52648.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libhmac-e46cb8143f624613.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\mul
ti-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcrypto_mac-925d9ef6ae4b5193.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsubtle-c37bc2b00e97ff00.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsha2-ace2dd5b19784
3bf.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libfake_simd-aa133cc27fa22141.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libblake2b_simd-aee6a663d36c0d08.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\rel
ease\\deps\\libconstant_time_eq-c658cc94fbe6b50e.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libarrayvec-88f3bf78f4321bc1.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libarrayref-cbaa68cdbc305db2.rlib" "F:\\rustcod
e\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsha3-437c0c5ef06e8fba.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libdigest-a839084f5f006a9d.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libopaque_debug-05ce5
882de270436.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libblock_buffer-cd917cc4be06fa9f.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libgeneric_array-aa73cbf095bd2f34.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\
\target\\release\\deps\\libtypenum-034803bac2f7aa61.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libblock_padding-1db94b794db05c08.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libbyte_tools-d333598573c712dd.rlib" "F
:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libkeccak-19ad87f1eabe79f0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libgmp-8ee5d53cabfe3ff8.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libnum_trait
s-aa7fdd97888c52ea.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libzeroize-b684541bb3596f9a.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsecp256k1-0cedecaf313f64ea.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\t
arget\\release\\deps\\librand-d6d637451260a871.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_xorshift-34b8c722fa652ad9.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_pcg-dd4e77a80a3a2ec0.rlib" "F:\\rust
code\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_hc-79c6b6647ed951da.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_chacha-3e3897938b67a796.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_is
aac-379297b4f2a7cb4c.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_core-ba87b9cb07336320.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_os-c90c6958c250e37c.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\
\target\\release\\deps\\librand_jitter-43228d7e23d1bb76.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_core-9bf81d9c0af68447.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcrypto-641881688c468d15.rlib" "F:\\r
ustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\liblibc-1a337355faef191a.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librustc_serialize-0c23f6d081fe1cfa.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libran
d-66e2bf1bb2b4a20e.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand-4fd1997ade6b8dc8.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libuuid-57e83e9bf94a27bc.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\r
elease\\deps\\librand-64fe7d1ff12dc3c2.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_chacha-a7f59c094346e00c.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libppv_lite86-ecb78556a3f267ec.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\mu
lti-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librand_core-29b09990d895d2e1.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libgetrandom-9c8e2d6122b970a6.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librocket_contrib-
ff74b4536216e331.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libserde_json-90eda275630547eb.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libryu-823c6f1a53741a46.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target
\\release\\deps\\libitoa-396ad9c01424f31b.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librocket-5a6333b84d5b047c.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libatty-a2c3f8b0fa13d6ad.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-part
y-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libbase64-afe07ed64e3fb8c3.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmemchr-093e47af9f4022f5.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtoml-7b68f70c86206613.rlib" "
F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libserde-e9aecfadc5a6818b.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libyansi-d662373364dbf861.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\librocket_
http-1e6241d31858fd10.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libhyper-4eb88fdc51ebb4ae.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmime-bc1ea3f86720264b.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\targe
t\\release\\deps\\liblog-56f5f03cbd755dcf.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\liblog-284f943c4ce0c13d.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcfg_if-31eaf206bdb44090.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party
-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\liblanguage_tags-5ec0ea271bd9256e.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtypeable-fd12ba52a9065402.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libtraitobject-34f20bed1
efe02d4.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libnum_cpus-1c958f0f1f35a51e.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libhttparse-af2068facb006bb2.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\rele
ase\\deps\\libunicase-13824eaef16a2911.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libbase64-b5e4d1d5122daabf.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsafemem-5521c56c5d451119.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-part
y-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libbyteorder-f5e63805e80f1b61.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libunicode_xid-15c30b6e8ef23867.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libstate-77406789ff851d1
0.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libindexmap-795b00fca348ae6f.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libcookie-77b77d7c8f6f3cf4.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\dep
s\\libtime-c3175b3c508c8bcf.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libwinapi-0f51a43659f90c6a.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\liburl-958d2791b3b93a75.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\
\target\\release\\deps\\libidna-7f9af993a6b87201.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libunicode_normalization-62ab15e926b00f04.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libunicode_bidi-4128539ae13d11ef.r
lib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libmatches-d072fd4019b81012.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libsmallvec-eddc8aac5b7d2830.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\
\libpercent_encoding-916e82758745343c.rlib" "F:\\rustcode\\multi-party-ecdsa-master\\target\\release\\deps\\libpear-2132d500a4843c9d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-
04d5009d5730db24.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-ba7e278c3a13e389.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rus
tlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-a64d8502b8eb1601.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-9a5c8ec03ac52eab.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\
.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libbacktrace-17de743b12ad001c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_deman
gle-34b741028331e100.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-f40156ef32076ee5.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustl
ib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-08d8f158086bc959.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-022ac961886c5a64.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\night
ly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-69474e7b1d414eba.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-ebb93cf09fb9da35
.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-242b1b8b2e396484.rlib" "C:\\Users\\VictorXie\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-
msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-3fccde95dc36895e.rlib" "ws2_32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "gmp.lib" "gmp.lib" "gmp.lib" "gmp.lib" "gmp.lib" "advapi32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "cfgmgr32.lib" "credui.lib" "fwpuclnt.lib" "gdi32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "msimg32.lib" "ntdll.lib" "openg
l32.lib" "secur32.lib" "synchronization.lib" "user32.lib" "winspool.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"

  = note: Non-UTF-8 output: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: \xce\xde\xb7\xa8\xb4\xf2\xbf\xaa\xca\xe4\xc8\xeb\xce\xc4\xbc\xfe\xa1\xb0gmp.lib\xa1\xb1\r\n
```

It seems like that the link.exe cannot find the gmp.lib, I tried to install mingw32-gmp with mingw-get and it didn't help. I don't know where the problem is, and how to fix it.

Comment: There are many reasons and answers on that problem. Try to search and find your case by : '`link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181'

Comment: Thanks for comment. However, my problem is not solved.  I don't know what the file 'gmp.lib' is, the installation of gmp doesn't produce this file and I cannot find any information on google. Very confused.